# Is there something wrong with my For loop?

Tags: python, json, loops, python-requests

I am trying to run a GET request to an API that returns JSON. The JSON response looks something like this:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "5C73B00598",
            "connectionState": "connected",
            "model": "PP152X"
        },
        {
            "id": "5C73B0059E",
            "connectionState": "connected",
            "model": "PP152X"
        },
        {
            "id": "4C72D012D8",
            "connectionState": "connected",
            "model": "PP203X"
        },
        {
            "id": "5C73B005DE",
            "connectionState": "connected",
            "model": "PP152X"
        },
        {
            "id": "5C73B005A2",
            "connectionState": "connected",
            "model": "PP152X"
        },
        {
            "id": "5C73B004A2",
            "connectionState": "disconnected",
            "model": "PP152X"
        },
        {
            "id": "5C73B0058B",
            "connectionState": "connected",
            "model": "PP152X"
        }
    ]
}
```

The simplified version of the script to just return one response from one API folder is this so far:

```
import requests
import json


url = "https://myurl.io/api/Customers/xxx/locations/xxx/nodes"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': 'xxx'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
str = response.text.strip()



json_str = json.loads(str)
print(len(json_str['nodes']))
i = 0
while i <= len(json_str['nodes']):
    #cus_list = json_str['nodes'][i]['connectionState']
    #cus_lists.append(cus_list)
    print(json_str['nodes'][i]['connectionState'])
    i += 1
```

When I run this script the while loop does not return 7 iterations of the 'connectionState' but rather just the first one.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but the condition in your while loop should use `<`. Also paste the actual output of that print statement and the response, not a truncated version of the output.

Comment: the condition aside, the loop seems fine. Are you sure it's returning 7 and not 1 from the api response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in json_str['nodes']:
    print(i['connectionState'])
```

This gives:

```
connected
connected
connected
connected
connected
disconnected
connected
```

Answer (score 0):

i must always be smaller then the len()

```
json_str = json.loads(str)
print(len(json_str['nodes']))
i = 0
while i < len(json_str['nodes']):
    #cus_list = json_str['nodes'][i]['connectionState']
    #cus_lists.append(cus_list)
    print(json_str['nodes'][i]['connectionState'])
    i += 1
```